# Sentence structure of hoax and dupe

Tags: grammar, verbs, sentence

Is this sentence structure available for the two verbs?

> hoax somebody out of something

> dupe somebody out of something

Comment: The construction is _to `Verb` s.o. out of s.t._, as in _to cheat him out of his change_, for instance. `Verb` here is always some bad action, it's a condemnation, often a hate word. Any verb that describes a bad act can work, mutatis mutandis.

Comment: To cheat s.o. out of s.t.  is the well-known usage. "He was duped out of thinking the money was real". Please note: "He was duped into thinking the money was real.", too. That said, you can adapt many things to the form. Same with hoaxed: You can be hoaxed into something or out of something. Nothing precludes that grammatically speaking.

Answer (score 2):

Those are resultative constructions in which the result is expressed by a prepositional phrase; they do sound natural,  but they are either not quite idiomatic (the first) or not attested in the dictionaries (the second).

The first construction is extremely rare, and in fact I find nothing for "out" ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hoaxed+me+out+of%2Choax+me+out+of%2Choax+him+out+of%2Choaxed+him+out+of%2Choax+them+out+of%2Choaxed+them+out+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=)). The unique case concerns the preposition "off" and dates from 1799.

([ref. 1](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Rosella/Xec4AQAAMAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22hoaxed+me%22&pg=PA182&printsec=frontcover)) I could have told her that Cyril had hoaxed me off the the field , but I was so chagrined that the […]

The second isn't found in dictionaries.

[OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/dupe_1), [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dupe%20someone%20out%20of), [lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/dupe), [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/dupe)

However, the dictionaries (OALD, Merriam-Webster and lexico) attest the unique possibility of using a prepositional phrases introduced by "*into*"; all the examples (21) in lexico are of that sort. Nevertheless, the preposition "*out*" is attested in the [literature](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=duped+%2A+out+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cduped%20%2A%20out%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bduped%20him%20out%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bduped%20them%20out%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bduped%20her%20out%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bduped%20me%20out%20of%3B%2Cc0#t2%3B%2Cduped%20*%20out%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bduped%20him%20out%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bduped%20them%20out%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bduped%20her%20out%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bduped%20me%20out%20of%3B%2Cc0); moreover, it appears that the usage is neither restricted to American English, although found a lot in the literature of that language, nor old, as show the following references that date from 2016 and 2017.

([ref. 2](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/The_Workhouse_Children/VU4fDQAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22duped+him+out+of%22&pg=PT176&printsec=frontcover)) She had duped him out of his position of Chairman and it still stung. He was a Magistrate, a man of learning, highly regarded in Bilston, yet this girl had ...

([ref. 3](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/The_Honorables/3agpDwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22duped+him+out+of%22&pg=PT210&printsec=frontcover)) Incensed that Blackbird had duped him out of The Great White Scot, he'd experienced something like a childish fit of pique and gone running to tittle-tattle ...

In conclusion, it can be said that the second verb can be used with "into" and "out of". As to the first one, following the author in reference "3" is a possibility that certain writers might find tempting.

Comment: The question was about the grammatical structure.

Answer (score 2):

Both exist but are not particularly common. I will start with the second which is more used than the first.

***To dupe somebody out of something*** is not recorded as a set phrase in the dictionaries, but you can find examples with it:

> It is alleged to ***have duped*** some 5,000 people ***out of*** as much as $40 million. ([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/dupe))

This [local police site](https://www.leics.police.uk/news/leicestershire/news/2021/january/warning-issued-after-elderly-people-duped-out-of-large-sums-of-money/) says:

> A warning has been issued after a number of elderly people were ***duped out of large sums of money*** after being contacted by bogus police officers.
> Since 10 December last year to date 17 reports of courier fraud have been received by the force.   With seven of those victims ***suffering losses*** of more than £135,000.

So the expression is used with the meaning of "suffering a loss by being deceived" and I found that it is used mostly [in the passive](https://eng.ichacha.net/zaoju/dupe%20out%20of.html) and followed by a sum of money or possessions:

> **someone** [*a victim]* **is duped out of** [*robbed through deceiving*] money/possessions

As for ***to hoax somebody out of something***, it does exist and it is used in the same way as "To dupe somebody out of something", but it is even more rare.

[The Daily Telegraph](https://www.dailytelegraph.com.au/news/nsw/australias-most-notorious-robberies-the-day-qantas-was-hoxed-out-of-500k/news-story/a24cedd101775118e64429ae039a2eab) has an article quoted by Wikipedia (which is how I found it). It says:

> Australia’s most notorious robberies: The day Qantas was hoaxed out of $500k.

But sometimes newspapers are not considered the most reliable sources, so I will provide another example from an English speaking author

> ***Hoaxed out of our*** wedding presents by a girl who is not going to have a wedding at all. I miss my brooch. My throat feels naked without it. (*[The Honorable Miss A Story of an Old-Fashioned Town](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=11bzasvFeTsC&pg=PT295&lpg=PT295&dq=%22hoaxed%20out%20of%22&source=bl&ots=y2RICJI1tF&sig=ACfU3U301IVsMsnZo0MSmIRh9yJTQXjNog&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjO1_SokuzxAhWNY8AKHYH6AwsQ6AEwBnoECAgQAw)*, by L. T. Meade)

So do they exist? Yes. Used mostly in the passive and followed by possessions. This [GNgram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hoax_VERB%2C+dupe_VERB%2C+hoaxed+out+of%2Cduped+out+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Choax_VERB%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdupe_VERB%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Choaxed%20out%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cduped%20out%20of%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Choax_VERB%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdupe_VERB%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Choaxed%20out%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cduped%20out%20of%3B%2Cc0) will show you how rare they are, and that ***to be duped out of something*** is used more than ***to be hoaxed out of***, which is probably due to the fact that "dupe" is more common than "hoax" as a verb:

[image]

It is worth noting that ***hoax*** is a word of English origin

> 1796 (used as a verb) "ridicule; deceive with a fabrication," 1808 (as a noun), probably an alteration of hocus "conjurer, juggler" (1630s), also "a cheat, impostor" (1680s); or else directly from *hocus-pocus*. ([etymoline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/hoax))

*Hocus Pocus* comes from early 17th century, from *hax pax max Deus adimax*, a pseudo-Latin phrase used as a magic formula by conjurors ([OxfordL](https://www.google.com/search?q=hoax%20etymology&biw=1372&bih=661&sxsrf=ALeKk039yb_spPuFRyOAvG3sJgqfKOkvkg%3A1626595669218&ei=VeHzYIL2DM-4gQbVp6aoCA&oq=hoax%20etymology&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAM6BwgAEEcQsAM6BAgjECc6BAguEEM6CggAELEDEIMBEEM6CAgAELEDEIMBOgUIABCRAjoECAAQAzoHCAAQhwIQFDoCCAA6BggAEAcQHjoLCAAQsQMQgwEQkQI6BAgAEEM6CggAELEDEIMBEAo6BAgAEApKBAhBGABQjOEWWJiVF2CQmRdoAXACeACAAZgBiAGzCZIBBDEzLjKYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6yAEIwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwjC9LmIlezxAhVPXMAKHdWTCYU4ChDh1QMIDg&uact=5#dobs=hocus-pocus))

***Dupe***, however, is an even older verb of French origin. It was formed from the noun *dupe* around 1704, meaning

> "to deceive, trick, mislead by imposing on one's credulity".

As a noun, *dupe* is dated in the 1680s:

> "one easily deceived or led astray by false representations," 1680s, from French dupe "deceived person," from duppe (early 15c.), thieves' jargon, perhaps from phrase de huppe "of the hoopoe," an extravagantly crested and reputedly stupid bird.
> ([etymoline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/dupe))